# Create temporary file and redirect output to it in one command

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I designed a custom script to grep a concatenated list of `.bash_history` backup files. In my script, I am creating a temporary file with `mktemp` and saving it to a variable `temp`. Next, I am redirecting output to that file using the `cat` command.

**Is there a means to create a temporary file (using `mktemp`), redirect output to it, then store it in a variable in one command, while preserving newline characters?**

The below snippet of code works just fine, but I have a feeling there is a more terse and canonical way to achieve this in one line – maybe using [process substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) or something of the like.

```
# Concatenate all .bash_history files into a temporary file `temp`.
temp="$(mktemp)"
cat "$HOME/.bash_history."* > $temp
trap 'rm -f $temp' 0

# Set `HISTFILE` shell variable to the `temp` file.
HISTFILE="$temp"

keyword="$1"

# Search for `keyword` using the `history` command
if [[ "$keyword" ]]; then
    # Enable history
    set -o history

    history | grep "$keyword"

    # Disable history
    set +o history
else
    echo -e "usage: search <keyword>"
    exit 0
fi
```

Comment: FYI, you've got some bad practices even in your example. Unquoted expansions can have undesired side effects (try your existing code if `IFS=/`, for instance), and all-caps variable names are [specified by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html) to be used for variables for meaning to the system and shell, while names with at least one lower-case character are reserved for application use. (See fourth paragraph behind the link).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy – Thanks for pointing out the issues with the all-caps and unquoted expansion. I will take note of those issues and make the corrections. In retrospect, I do feel a little obtuse for not cleaning that up.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy – What is the proper way to make the expansion safe? I though double quoting filename expansions disable the special meaning of *, ?, and [].

Comment: Correct, double-quoting is the Right Thing. (It's not just glob characters, but also characters in IFS). See http://shellcheck.net/ for automated detection of places where quoting is inadequate if you ever have questions. (Note that it's lax when variables are hardcoded to values that don't need to be quoted, so if you want shellcheck to give you full advice on how to quote `$var` everywhere it's used, define it dynamically -- as with `var=$1` or `var=$(somecommand)` rather than `var=foo`).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy – when I double quote, such as `"$HOME/.bash_history.*"` it looks for that literal filename and doesn't expand like it should. e.g. `.bash_history.10-2016`. Instead it looks for the literal `.bash_history.*`

Comment: Right -- if you still want the glob to be expanded, put it outside the double quotes. It's a character-by-character attribute (meaning a string can be formed of substrings quoted in different ways). Thus, `"$HOME/.bash_history"*`, or `"$HOME"/.bash_history*`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy – Thanks. I thought you were referring to the entire glob, not the command substitution and the preceding piece of the filename. Point noted; thank you for the explanation.

Comment: Frankly, I'd forgotten the context of the question, so I was giving the answer for parameter expansions and assuming that you *didn't* want glob characters expanded. Thank you for following up. :)

Comment: To be clear, are you wanting to set and read a shell variable in one go?  Something like the **mythical**:

 ` cat "$HOME/.bash_history."* > temp=$(mktemp)`

Answer (score 5):

If you're comfortable with the side effect of making the assignment conditional on `tempfile` not previously having a nonempty value, this is straightforward via the `${var:=value}` expansion:

```
cat "$HOME/.bash_history" >"${tempfile:=$(mktemp)}"
```

Comment: It seems that the output redirection to the `tempfile` variable is occurring before the file assignment from the `mktemp` command leaving me with an empty (truncated) file.

Comment: That proposed flow of events isn't feasible: `mktemp` creates the file before it writes the name to stdout and closes its stdout stream; it can't be read until after it's no longer an open stream, so `$(mktemp)` can't complete evaluation until after the file already exists.

Comment: That said, so I can look at behavior in practice -- which version of bash are you testing with? And as I specify in my introductory paragraph, *do* be sure that `tempfile` is unset or set to a zero-byte string at the time when this code runs -- if it already exists, it'll be unchanged, so you will indeed have a leaked empty temporary file left behind.

Comment: I hear you loud and clear @CharlesDuffy. I tinkered with it for a while...and going back to your earlier comment, it probably isn't good design to cram it in one command anyway.

Comment: Bash version: GNU bash, version 4.4.0(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0)

Comment: It does work, as you mentioned in your answer, when `tempfile` has a value. e.g. `tempfile='0'; cat "$HOME/.bash_history."* > "${tempfile:=$(mktemp)}"`

Comment: FYI, I hacked together this solution but it doesn't quite suffice in my case because it doesn't respect newlines `temp=$(< <(cat "$HOME/.bash_history."*))`

Comment: That actually *does* retain newlines, though I don't know why you'd prefer it over `temp=$(cat "$HOME/.bash_history."*)`. Look at how you're printing the output.

Comment: Oh. Or are you referring to the process substitution as creating a temporary file? On Linux, or other operating systems with `/dev/fd`, it doesn't strictly create a regular file -- instead using `/dev/fd` (or `/proc/self/fd`) to refer to an anonymous fd created with `mkfifo()`.

Comment: re: what I meant above, `echo "$temp"` will retain newlines, whereas `echo $temp` will discard them.

Comment: Yes, the snippet in my comment is my attempt at using process substitution instead of `mktemp` to create the temp file. I should have mentioned it in the question; the temp file is not needed after the completion of the script, so that is why I was leaning towards this approach over creating a standard file – easier to cleanup. There may be other benefits (and drawbacks) to doing this, but I was under the impression this was the convention.

Comment: Sure. My point is that if process substitution is adequate to your purposes, you didn't really need a temporary file in the first place (and the question could/should have been asked in a manner that made your actual needs clear).

Comment: You are 100% correct and I apologize for the ambiguity. In all honesty, I didn't realize there were so many ways to handle such as situation as the one delineated in my question. I editted the question in an attempt to correct this. I will dig into the literature and see if there is a way to achieve this like you said with process substitution feeding directly to the HISTFILE variable.

Answer (score 3):

```
cat myfile.txt | f=`mktemp` && cat > "${f}"
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is more than one way to do it. I found following to be working for me:

```
cat myfile.txt > $(echo "$(mktemp)")
```

Also don't forget about `tee`:

```
cat myfile.txt | tee "$(mktemp)" > /dev/null
```

Comment: What benefit does `cat myfile.txt > $(echo "$(mktemp)")` have over `cat myfile.txt > "$(mktemp)"`? Also, this is missing the "store it in a variable" component of the question.